# init.d script for Mojolicious app using Carton

Tags: perl, mojolicious, init.d

I have a Mojolicious app that I would like to run automatically when the server starts.  Normally, if I want to deploy the application, I use `carton install` to grab the appropriate dependencies, then I run `carton exec -- hypnotoad script/myapp` and I'm up and running.

I've created an init.d script that starts|stops the application by calling `carton exec -- hypnotoad script/myapp`, but [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) doesn't seem to be working properly.  Instead, I get `sudo: carton: command not found` followed by a number of `Can't locate <MODULE>.pm in @INC...` errors.

How do I go about making Carton available to an init.d script?  Or how do I run a Carton command from an init.d script?

Comment: See also [How to make `sudo` preserve $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191/45537) and [How to set path for sudo commands](https://superuser.com/q/927512/278134)

Comment: In general it's a good idea to use the full path to each executable you run from init or cron scripts (in this case, that includes carton, hypnotoad, and script/myapp).

Comment: Full paths solved the problem.